# Why result of put() from HashMap is compared with null when add into a HashSet in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, addition, hashset

I try to understand the implementation of `HashSet` and I see that it uses the `HashMap` internally.
And when you `add` in an `HashSet`, internally you `put` in an `HashMap` like below:

```
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;

private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();

public boolean add(E e) {
   return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

But what I don't understand is why they use this `==null`.

This is the signature oh put method:

```
public V put(K key, V value)
```

I don't understand why the result of `put` is compared with `null`.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc of `Map.put`? Do you understand the return value of `Set.add`?

Comment: And for `HashSet.add`? Based on those two you can quite easily guess what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

The Javadoc of [`Set.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) says:

> Returns:
>   true if this set did not already contain the specified element

The Javadoc of [`Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) says:

> Returns:
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

So, whether or not `null` is returned by the `put` indicates whether or not the key/value pair was already in the map, and thus the key was "in the set".

Answer (score 1):

## Facts

- [`Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V))  Returns the previous value associated with key, or `null` if there was no mapping for key.
- [`Set.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) Returns `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element

## Explanation

- If the element was not in the inner `Map`, the `put` returns `null` so the equals is `True` and means the value wasn't there before
- If the element was in the inner `Map`, `put` would return previous value, in most case different of `null` , equality false is returned as there was a previous vlaue